# Create an Azure api app based on owin

Tags: owin, azure-api-apps

I'm trying to create an Azure API App like here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-dotnet-create-api-app/
But, it seems not based on Owin.
If I look in the references, I can see old things like System.Web ...

Is there a way to create an Azure API App based on Owin ?

Answer (score 2):

System.Web comes with Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb. 
I'm in fact able to create an owin startup class and remove global.asax